# Generics Picker View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I am trying to create a generic UI Picker using Generics. As part of my implementation, I created the GenericRow object to be displayed in UIPicker. But I am facing some issue. It may be basic one but couldn't find out.

```
struct GenericRow<T> {
    let type: T
    let title: String
    public init(type: T, title: String) {
        self.type = type
        self.title = title
    }
 }
```

The next is GenericDataSource to handle UIPickerViewDataSource and UIPickerViewDelegate.

```
class GenericPickerDataSource<T>: NSObject, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    public var items: [GenericRow<T>]

    public init(withItems items: [GenericRow<T>]) {
        self.items = items
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return items[row].title
    }
}
```

Then, I am creating an manager to handle picker show / hide functionalities. Kindly note that this is also generic and doesn't know anything about the GenericRow type.

```
class GenericPickerManager {
    static func showPicker(_ dataSource: GenericPickerDataSource<Any>) {}

    static func hidePicker() {}
}
```

Example Input:

```
struct State {
    let identifier: String
    let name: String
}

let CA = State(identifier: "CA", name: "California")
let CLT = State(identifier: "CLT", name: "Charlotte")
let IL = State(identifier: "IL", name: "Illinois")

let states = [CA, CLT, IL]

let items = states.map {
    GenericRow<State>(type: $0, title: $0.name)
}

let dataSource = GenericPickerDataSource(withItems: items)
```

Now when I try to show picker from my class, I am getting an error.

```
GenericPickerManager.showPicker(dataSource)
```

> Cannot convert value of type GenericPickerDataSource<State> to
>   expected argument type GenericPickerDataSource<Any>.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I could fix this by calling GenericPickerManager.showPicker(dataSource as Any). But would like to know if this approach of using Any is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Any` and generics don't work together very well. Make `GenericPickerManager` also generic:

```
class GenericPickerManager<T> {
    static func showPicker(_ dataSource: GenericPickerDataSource<T>) {}

    static func hidePicker() {}
}
```